# Opencart: Is there a limit on using design layouts on products?

Tags: opencart

I am using **Opencart v.1.5.6.1** (with about 1000 products & about 50 categories) and I am wondering if there is **a limit on using design layouts on products** or if there are **performance issues** by doing this.

I would like to have about 100 Product Layout Overrides and 20 Category Layout Overrides.

Will that be a problem?

Comment: Really depends on your server, and what you consider a problem but generally it'll be the 1000 products not the layouts that will cause you issues with performance - so no it's unlikely. The easiest way to try it with dummy layouts

Comment: @JayGilford Thank you for your comment! The server is looking good with the 1000 products (so far). What do you mean with **dummy layouts**?

Comment: I mean if you want to test it quickly, just add 100 layouts that are identical, then you can add your real ones at a later time